# MVC Get givenname and surname of Azure Active Directory authenticated user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm able to obtain the user name (email format) of the authenticated user using:

`var autenticateduser = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;`

Using QuickWatch window I am able to find the givenname and surname using the following expression. Is there a more clean way to obtain this info?

`(new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<System.Security.Claims.Claim>(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)(HttpContext.User.Identity)).Claims)).Items[5]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about

```
ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
string welcome = string.Format("Welcome, {0} {1}!", cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value, cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

This way you can get non standard claims also, you just need to know the name of the key, obtainable for example from the openidconnect YOURDOMAIN/.well-known/openid-configuration JSON response.

> Hello @User.Claims.Single(a => a.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname").Value!

[system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.claims API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.claims(v=vs.110).aspx)